# Closing pure CSS Hamburger menu on click

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

I added code to hamburger menu below. I want to close menu after click on specific section.

For example, if you click on 'contact' section menu should hide and move me to contact section on page. I waste about one hour and really don't have an idea how to fix it, menu still appears on screen.

```css
/* CORE STYLES */
:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(13, 110, 139, 0.75);
  --overlay-color: rgba(24, 39, 51 , 0.85);
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

.showcase {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/533923/pexels-photo-533923.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260') no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.showcase .showcase-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* MENU STYLES */
.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Hamburger Line */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

/* Hamburger Lines - Top & Bottom */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}

/* Moves Line Down */
.menu-wrap .hamburger > div::after {
  top: 10px;
}

/* Toggler Animation */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

/* Turns Lines Into X */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

/* Show Menu */
.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .toggler:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition:  opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu > div > div > ul > li > a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
  <title>Hamburger Menu Overlay</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
    <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <header class="showcase">
    <div class="container showcase-inner">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maiores sint impedit delectus quam molestiae explicabo cum facere ratione veritatis.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead using a `:checked` input which is an issue if you want to unchecked it  while you click on a link (make a choice click the input or the link) , you may use `:focus` that can easily be lost clicking anywhere else.

Possible example

```css
/* CORE STYLES */



:root {
  --primary-color: rgba(13, 110, 139, 0.75);
  --overlay-color: rgba(24, 39, 51, 0.85);
  --menu-speed: 0.75s;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 3rem;
}

.showcase {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.showcase:before {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/533923/pexels-photo-533923.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260") no-repeat center center/cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.showcase .showcase-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.showcase p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* MENU STYLES */

.menu-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-wrap .toggler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Hamburger Line */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s 0.4s ease;
}


/* Hamburger Lines - Top & Bottom */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
}


/* Moves Line Down */

.menu-wrap .hamburger>div::after {
  top: 10px;
}


/* Toggler Animation */

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus>div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}


/* Turns Lines Into X */

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus>div:before,
.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus>div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/* Rotate On Hover When Checked */

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus>div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}


/* Show Menu */

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus~.menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus~.menu>div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: var(--menu-speed);
}

.menu-wrap .hamburger:focus~.menu>div>div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.menu-wrap .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div {
  background: var(--overlay-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  display: flex;
  flex: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu-wrap .menu>div>div>ul>li>a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.4s ease;
}


/* whatever only for the demo */

div.boxe {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 10;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
  font-size: 5vmax
}

div.boxe:target {
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(13, 110, 139, 1);
 
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <!--<input type="checkbox" class="toggler">  removed for a tabindex attribute -->
  <div tabindex="0" class="hamburger">
    <!-- give it a tabindex to make it clikable and be focused -->
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#aa">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bb">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cc">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#dd">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 
<header class="showcase">
  <div class="container showcase-inner">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas maiores sint impedit delectus quam molestiae explicabo cum facere ratione veritatis.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</header>


<!-- whatever, just for a demo -->

<div id="aa" class="boxe"><a href="#">top</a>box A</div>
<div id="bb" class="boxe"><a href="#">top</a>box B</div>
<div id="cc" class="boxe"><a href="#">top</a>box C</div>
<div id="dd" class="boxe"><a href="#">top</a>box D</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the X doesn't work now :(

Comment: @MaicolBen sorry , i do not understand what you mean by : *'the X doesn't work'*  this answers the op question, but maybe the op original code is what you expected ?

Comment: I mean closing the X icon after the sidebar is open. Maybe wasn't expected in the question but as user in common UI, I'd expect it. Anyway, I solved it by adding `pointer-events: none` to the .hamburger

Comment: @MaicolBen good for you ;) . for a personnal different  issue, you may also have asked your own question. SO is not a pick'n go code samples at first.

Comment: I don't think so, if you check the question, the X works in the question's code but your code answer broke it.

Comment: @MaicolBen that was the deal to close it clicking anywhere else, else there was no question ;) -/-  *I want to close menu after click on specific section.*  -/- first-line of the question ;)

Comment: Oh, my reading skills are awful, very sorry. I hope my example helped other people.